# How to generate integer autoincrement ID feild in cakePHP using ichikaway mongodb plugin

Tags: php, mongodb, cakephp, cakephp-2.2

I am absolute dumb to mongoDB. I am using  [ichikaway cakephp-mongodb](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb/) plugin to use mongoDB data-source in my cakephp 2.2 Application.

Here is snippet of my model User.php file:

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel {
    public $primaryKey = '_id';

    var $mongoSchema = array(
            'username'=>array('type'=>'string'),
            'password'=>array('type'=>'string'),
            'created'=>array('type'=>'datetime'),
            'modified'=>array('type'=>'datetime'),
            );

    public $validate = array( ...
```

This is generating an unique object id as shown in following mongoDB Document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52cd469faca7b9880a8b4568"),
    "username" : "admin",
    "password" : "7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b",
    "modified" : ISODate("2014-01-08T12:37:51.292Z"),
    "created" : ISODate("2014-01-08T12:37:51.292Z")
}
```

I know that this objectID can be perfectly used as we do with unique Auto Increment Integer ID in SQL databases. As I can access it using _id field.

But even though, I want to generate Integer Auto Increment ID here. Please guide me.

Comment: I would imagine that cakephp has a beforeSave() event on the active record at which point you would findandmodify the counter collection for the ID and return the incremented ID

Comment: Yes! Thanks... :) I haven't thought about it!! This is a good quick fix for to this problem. But I believe there must have been a standard way to this which may indirectly involve mongoDB API to do this.

Comment: I think the next best thing is to involve behavoiurs in this or you can go down the same route as this guy: https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb/issues/16 but a good google search makes me believe that there is currently no good extension or add on for cakephp to do this

Comment: Please note, that auto increment becomes unmanageable if you have more than one data node. Auto increment fields inherently don't work well in a distributed environment.